# How to add validation on same database field for different names in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a database users. It has an email field.

I have two input fields with names users[email] and manager.email. I want the validation of uniqueness to be on users table. Here is what have I tried it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-8">{{ Form::input('text', 'users[email]', '', ['class' => "form-control", 'maxlength' => 255, 'id' => "userEmail", 'placeholder' => "Email Address"]) }}</div>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-8">{{ Form::input('text', 'manager[email]', '', ['class' => "form-control", 'maxlength' => 255, 'id' => "email", 'placeholder' => "Manager Email Address"]) }}</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My validator is as follows:

```
$validationRules = ['users.email' => 'email|required|unique:users', 
'manager.email' => 'email|required|unique:users', 
];
```

So, when I validator it returns a message stating :

```
Unknown column 'manager.email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `manager`.`email` = 'xyz@email.com')
```

Please guide me through this or suggest me a better option to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine your issue is because you're not specifying the column name in your unique rule.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique (look under **Specifying A Custom Column Name**)

Try changing:

```
'manager.email' => 'email|required|unique:users'
```

to:

```
'manager.email' => 'email|required|unique:users,email'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesnt help.

Comment: It worked. I had tried the same however, I guess Laravel must have cached the previous view.